# CRON Alert stock is not working, but cron_schedule show success

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, cron, out-of-stock

I'm using cron to send product stock alerts, and currently using `magento 1.9.1`. I have already changed the file `config.xml` in the path `app\code\core\Mage\ProductAlert\etc`

```
<jobs>
   <catalog_product_alert>           
      <run>
         <model>productalert/observer::process</model>
      </run>
   </catalog_product_alert>
</jobs>
```

To

```
<jobs>
   <catalog_product_alert>
      <schedule>
         <cron_expr>* * * * *</cron_expr>
      </schedule>            
      <run>
         <model>productalert/observer::process</model>
      </run>
   </catalog_product_alert>
</jobs>
```

When I run `cron.php`, the table `cron_schedule` is populated with five (5) `catalog_product_alert` rows. Then I run `cron.php` again in the appropriated time, and both columns "**executed**" and "**finished**" are updated and the status is flagged as success, but the table `product_alert_stock` was not updated and no e-mail was sent. Cron table show me the job was run, but it wasn't. It's just flagged as success.

Now, if I run `www.mydomain.com/productalert/add/testObserver/`, the email arrives, the table is updated and all works fine.

I've already gave `777 permission` to `cron.php` and `cron.sh`, but it not works too. I know this isn't a good security practice, but it's for tests purposes.

Why the cron service can't run this job? What I'm missing?

Comment: What is your `testOberver` method? Add that as an edit to help us debug.